# Digital character sheets?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, character-sheets, tool-recommendation

I find it annoying and impractical to go to the library to print off character sheets (I don't have a printer at my house), so I decided to see if there were any character sheet apps for my 4th gen iPod.  There are a couple, but the only ones compatible cost money.  I can afford both of them, but I'm not sure which is best (I don't want to wind up buying one that doesn't work properly).  One is RPG Scribe, which is 2 dollars.  The other is real sheet unlimited: D&D 3.5 edition, which is 3 dollars.  Which one should I get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My preference is to use online sheets, particularly those at [The Tangled Web](http://www.thetangledweb.net). You can even save the Web page and open it on any device that has a browser, even without internet, though your character picture *may* not work depending on how it gets saved.

These are free, and pretty thorough in terms of details. I have never felt even the slightest need to pay for a sheet, not have I known anyone who has bought one.

Example:

- [Oberyn, arena champion](http://thetangledweb.net/forums/profiler/view_char.php?cid=51173)

Comment: I went to take a look at this, but would have to go through the process of registering to even get a concept of what I would be getting. Not a huge deal of course, but a screenshot of the resulting character sheet would be nice.

Comment: @DCShannon You can look at existing sheets without registering. Added a link to one of my characters.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a free good solution as school project, but for Android device only, sorry. I leave the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.jdr.DicePaper&hl=fr) here in case someone else read the thread and is interested, since the title doesn't specify iPod (or any iOS device).

It has very basic design but like the name mention it, it provides dice and paper: you can define your character sheet template, then fill it and launch dice (even sort 50d10 for World of darkness adepts). You can also export/import character sheet templates so that your whole team get the same kind of character sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Google Sheets. It's helpful to have it autocalculate any stats possible, and you can create a shared folder in google drive so that the DM can have access to all of the players Character sheets, Backstory, Images, and anything else added to the folder.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.SE!  Take a look at the [tour] and [help] if you want to get a better idea of exactly how this site is different from most forums.  Your answer is pretty good, but you probably want to link to the specific google sheet template that you use, or the site that you found the sheets on.  As it stands, your answer basically says "build your own sheet on Google", which isn't very helpful.  If you add a link to the sheet you use, this will be a much better answer.

Comment: I've never actually played 3.5, but there are a number of 3.5 Templates available for Sheets.
The one below isn't the best looking template I've seen, But it seems to be the most encompassing. 
https://docs.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0Al_g3F7rSfI2dG8tLTZTdGZEUVBHOUpUc1FEZGx2a3c&mode=public