# Is there a D&D 3.5 character manager for Android?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tool-recommendation

Currently I'm using [Javascript 3.5 Character Generator Lite](http://www.pathguy.com/cg35lite.htm) - we are back to simple tools. And indeed it works on my Android phone. But it lacks save and level-up features.

Is there a tool for Android that can do this? Bonus points would be:

- Free. If not free, there must be a way to try before paying. Business model represented by [Spellbook - D&D 3.5 by Shaking Earth Digital](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zalzala.spellbook&hl=en) (free download, but pay for each character) is not acceptable. I need at least a week with at least one character to decide if that's what I need and compare it with it's price.
- Spells and resource management. Not required, but it would be nice to have it in my phone in case of loosing paper.
- Dice rolling - Again, not required, but would make playing next to little children a bit safer.

Comment: Although I personally hate Javascript, your first link is really good actually!

Answer (score 1):

I answered a related (but more generalist) question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33448/digital-character-sheets/40920#40920). [My solution](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.jdr.DicePaper&hl=en) is very minimalist since you have to enter the empty character sheet by yourself, but this allow you to have many homebrew rule change if you want without breaking anything.

On the other hand, the rules are not implemented so it's really like virtual paper rather than a software (although this allow you to manage spells and resource the way you want).

It's free and you can roll dices (and even sort/sum the results). Your character will be saved locally but the empty template can be exported in xml and re-imported on other device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try our own (it's free):
This one syncs with the cloud (quite useful) and perform many calculations, and has a modern look & feel.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dgtalize.dndcharmanager